# Glue ETL Job is failing while accessing Empty Redshift table using gluecontext

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am facing issue while accessing Empty Redshift Tables from GLueContext Dynamic frame. The table is visible in Glue Catalog. But when I try accessing it from Glue ETL, it is throwing error on below mentioned line of code:

```
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database=<redshift_database>,
    table_name=<table_name>,
    redshift_tmp_dir=<redshift_temp>,
    transformation_ctx=<transformation_ctx>
)
```

If I insert 1 row in the Redshift table and run the job it is running successfully.

I started facing this issue from Monday, April 27, 2020. Earlier, I was able to run Glue ETL jobs on Empty Redshift tables.

Did anyone face this issue?
Why is Glue Job Failing for empty Redshift tables?

Error Message:

> An error occurred while calling o118.getDynamicFrame. The specified key does not exist. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: NoSuchKey; Request ID: BD60647947F6BA52; S3 Extended Request ID: JuIqVpL2nJuxdVtR4pgK/kH5TamNFlcFC7EfMOpdxgT/1tlBy/nnPnPcsqurIf24zaDKAcbw0Hk=)

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine now, without making any changes